# Generating 'word of the day' via PHP Random Number

Tags: php, math, random, numbers

I'm stuck with a small issue and don't want to generate my own algo for random number.

I've to Display 'word of the day' on website, it has to change only once per day and all data is stored in XML. At pageload I read xml file by simpleXml Parser in php and then generate a random number between 0, length of array and output a term + definition.

But i dont want it to change with every refresh, nor do I want to save it on server in database.

So how can I generate a random number between 0 to N, which would give same value for a span of 24 hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set the current date as Seed without hours, minutes and seconds.

```
srand(mktime(0, 0, 0));
$wordIndex = rand(0, $wordCount);
```

It will return the same number for one Day.

Answer (score 6):

Option 1: No random numbers, just increase the index by one every day. It will look random enough since no one knows your file. If that is not good enough, randomize the input file (shuffle it once and safe it out again).

Option 2: Use today's date as the seed for the random number generator.

Comment: the words are arranged alphabetically and I also have a search functionality. Having an index incremented by 1 each day will not be feasible here... Will try option 2, didn't know PP had option for seed based random number.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
  srand(date("ymd"));
  echo rand();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to store it, then use something, that is connected to daily cycle, for example, the date, or weekday.