# How to display a different message read from a file every day of the week in php?

Tags: php, database, function

I have a php function that reads a line (random message) from a file and displays it on my web page. It displays a new message every time I click refresh, but I want it to display the message for a day (it should change at midnight). Is it possible to do it with another function, implying my database? Or with a JS function?

EDIT
This is the function (not my code):

```php
function loadMessagesFromFile()
{
    $path = ROOT_PATH. '/messages.txt';
    $file = fopen($path,"r");
    $messages = array();
    while($data = fgets($file))
    {
        $messages[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $messages;
}
```

This is how I use it to display the message:

```
$messages_from_file = loadMessagesFromFile();
$key = array_rand($messages_from_file);
$full_text = $messages_from_file[$key];
```

LATER EDIT

```
I found the answer here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815614/generating-word-of-the-day-via-php-random-number#:~:text=Just%20set%20the%20current%20date,same%20number%20for%20one%20Day.>
```

Comment: _Seeding_ the random generator with the day number (within the year) would probably make the most sense.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This does not look pretty random to me, so why not simply use the date as the selector?

Comment: I did not try anything yet. I have just searched for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple possibilities:

1. Create a file with only one line every day taken from the other file
2. Create a cron who will be executed ad midnight who will get a random message and set it in database or cache.
3. If you want a different message per people but persist one day, you can use the local storage of the visitor to store the message with the current date and if the date stored is different from the current date, you change it.

Answer (score -1):

1. get total lines from your file
2. Use a database or file and store a random number daily.
3. Use that number to read a random message from the file.
4. Use cron to update random numbers at midnight in your database or file.

So, for 24 hours the same message will be displayed.

```
function getRandomNo(): int {
    $path = ROOT_PATH. '/randomno.txt';
    $file = fopen($path,"r");
    $data = fread($file,100);
    fclose($file);

    if($data) {
        $parts = explode('=',$data);
        if($parts[0] != date("Y-m-d")) {
            $randomNo = rand(0,100);
            overWrite($randomNo);
        } else {
            $randomNo = $parts[1];
        }
    } else {
        $randomNo = rand(0,100);
        overWrite($randomNo);
    }

    return $randomNo;
}

function overWrite(int $randomNo): void {
    $path = ROOT_PATH. '/randomno.txt';
    $file = fopen($path,"w+");
    $data = date("Y-m-d").'='.$randomNo;
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}

$messages_from_file = loadMessagesFromFile();
$key = getRandomNo();
$full_text = $messages_from_file[$key];
```

Comment: Let me know if needed I can share code snippet.

Comment: My function just reads line by line from .txt file and displays a line. What would be better to use a table in database or another file to store the random number? If you have any code sample, can you please share it? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).